# Erase * in Windows command line without prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Ok, I am trying to delete some files using a Windows script, and I would like to use internal commands to delete all the files (del mydirectory*) without a confirmation prompt.  The internet says that, by default, there should be no confirmation prompt.

However, there is a confirmation prompt.  Is there an easy, simple way to delete the files without the prompt? Or a way to automate the deletion--somehow input the "Y" on the next line of the batch script or something?

I am using the command prompt in windows server 2012.  All I know is that the Dos commands seem to work, and I would like to run del * without a prompt...but the windows unicorns, pillows and padded corners are slapping me upside the head.

Command is: 
     del *

Comment: Please show the command you used. Also, this type of question would belong on Super User, after you've completed it.

Comment: Do you *really* mean MS-DOS, or are you talking about the Windows command line? Which **version** of Windows are you on?

Comment: windows command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
del *.* /Q
```

You can find del command options with /? param